# Read value of bits in a 32bit unsigned integer in Java

Tags: java, integer, bit

I am trying to read the value of bits in an Integer in Java. I'm reading the status of a hardware device which says it returns:

Header (4 bytes):
1B + FF + 02 + m
where m is the number of bytes of status data following the m. Byte 3 should define the type of status packet.

Status Summary (4 bytes):
Each of the 32 bits of the status summary is available as a flag for the following purposes, Note that this is a 32-bit unsigned integer. Each Bit (0-31) is mostly 0 or 1.

When I read the status from the USB device, it usually returns "18". So I tried a function like so:

```
status_printer_error = getBit(status,0);
public int getBit(int n, int k) {
    return (n >> k) & 1;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work though. I also tried just looping through all the bits:

```
for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
            int s = status_sum & (1 << i);
            Log.d(TAG,"bit: " + s);
        }
```

But the results seem wrong, I am getting 0,2,0,0,16,0,0...etc (all 0's).

Here is the PDF document for the device. The printing functions all work for me, it's just the status part I'm struggling with (page 51):
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hengstler.com%2Fgfx%2Ffile%2Fshop%2Fprinter%2FeXtendo_X-80%2FD-684-112_EmulationCommandSetReference_eXtendo-E-V1_07.pdf&ei=8BaeUuLII5H3oASAxoLQDw&usg=AFQjCNF6iwxBwDsotnKUYmeWwis6ZIqX2w&bvm=bv.57155469,d.cGU

Comment: There are no unsigned ints in java as far as I know...

Comment: It doesn't matter here, @Rogue, as only the bits are taken apart.

Comment: @Michael - So 2+16 is 18, what did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be treating it as an `int` at all.  The reason is that your data comes as bytes, you are turning it into an `int` and then decoding the `int` back into bytes.

I would just parse each byte as you get it. but in answer to your question, I would print the `int` value as hex with `Integer.toHexString(status)` to make sure your `int` is composed as you expect.  Your `18` as an int value appears to be wrong so trying to turn this into bits won't make it any more correct.

The first thing I would check is that you are not doing this.

```
int i = inputStream.read(); // is 8-bit not 32-bit.
```

This returns an `int` value but it is an 8-bit int value, not a 32-bit int value.

Comment: The docs I am referring to says that the status packet is returned as a 32 bit unsigned int. But when I run: Integer.toHexString(status), this returns me 12

Comment: @Michael That means you are not reading it as a 32-bit int.  My guess is you are only reading the byte length.

Comment: Yes it does seem like the method is only returning the length...need to reach out to the vendor at this point I think. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael By guess is you are only reading one byte, can you try reading more bytes?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the method on the hardware device api only returns the length and parsing one of the arguments returned all the details I needed. So

```
public int getBit(int n, int k) {
    return (n >> k) & 1;
}
```

worked when given the correct int.